# How can we map multiple tables in Mapper.xml using mybatis-spring?

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am creating a project in which i have to fetch the records from multiple tables. For that i am using spring and mybatis. My question is that for multiple tables there should be only one Mapper.xml. But how can we map multiple tables in one mapper.xml. How our Mapper.xml looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you are talking about how to deal with different tables, it's not a good practice to use one single mapper. It's better to split it and register your mappers in many ways. One of the examples is

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/PostMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Please refer to http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers for more details.

But if you talking about how to query by joining multiple tables you could achieve it by using the Result Maps. Please refer to http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Advanced_Result_Maps